# Group similar but exact words and their abbreviation in python

Tags: python-3.x, machine-learning, grouping

I have a question regarding grouping of similar words and their abbreviation into one group for example I have list of words give below:

1. artificialintelligence
2. Artificial Intelligence
3. AI
4. Machine Learning
5. ML
6. Data Analytics
7. Data & Analytics

I want to group these words into [Artificial intelligence, Machine Learning, Data Analytics]

I have used difflib.get_close_matches() but that does not give me desired result For example this is how difflib group: Information Technology': ['Information Technology','Mobile Technology', 'newtechnology']

I have also used fuzz.token_set_ratio() but that also does not provide me the desired result. Neither Levenshtein does.

If there is any Machine learning algorithm or any python library please let me know.

Comment: Have you looked into word embeddings like Glove oder word2vec? gensim is a very powerful framework in that regard: https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/

Comment: Please do take some time to read [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and notice that questions asking us to *recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource* are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

You have 2 types of problems:

1) You have strings that are equal by substrings, such as Data Analytics and Data & Analytics. To solve this, you have one quick solution.

```
def check_if_substring( str1 = "Data Analytics" , str2 = "Data & Analytics" ):
    str1 = str1.lower()
    str2 = str2.lower()

    split_str_1 = str1.split() 
    split_str_2 = str2.split()
    is_same = True
    for s in split_str_1:
       if( not s in split_str_2 ):
           is_same = False

    if is_same: return True

    is_same = True
    for s in split_str_2:
       if( not s in split_str_1 ):
           is_same = False        

    return is_same
```

2) you have the initials problem. matching ML with Machine Learning. This is more tricky. you need to detect that certain strings are abbreviations (probably because they hardly ever have more than 4 characters) and match them with the initials of the strings that are not abbreviations. Using dynamic programming to align them